# stream data into a byte array

Tags: c++, stream, bytebuffer

I have to admit that I am a bit confused at the moment, so sorry if the question isnt quite clear or trivial (actually I hope it is the latter)....

I am sending an array of bytes across the network and would like to do something like this on the sender side:

```
size_t max_size = 100;
uint8_t buffer[size];
idontknowwhat_t x{buffer};    
uint16_t size = 11;                 // total number of bytes in the buffer
uint16_t id_a,id_b,id_c;            // some ids
uint8_t  a,b,c;                     // some data
x << size << id_a << a << id_b << b << id_c << c;
someMethodToSend(buffer,size);
```

and on the receiver side something like this:

```
size_t max_size = 100;
uint8_t buffer[size];
someMethodToReceive(buffer);
idontknowwhat_t x{buffer};
uint16_t size;
x >> size;
for (uint16_t i=0; i<size-2; i++) {
    uint16_t id;
    uint8_t data;
    x >> id >> data;
    std::cout << id << " " << data;
}
```

So my aim is basically to avoid ugly casts and manually incrementing a pointer while being able to have `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` (and possibly also `uint32_t`) in the buffer. The data I put in the buffer here is just an example, and I am aware that I need to take care of the byte order when sending over the network (and it would be fine if I had to do this "manually").

Is there something that I can use in place of my hypothetical `idontknowwhat_t` ?

Comment: I think [`boost::asio::streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html) should be ok, but I'm not sure if the internal buffer it uses is ok for your use case.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think I already took a look at it, but after reading in too many different places about streams I got a bit confused. I will give it a try, thx for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really avoid doing ugly casts, but at least you can hide them into the `idontknowwhat_t` class's `operator>>` and `operator<<` functions. And using templates, you could limit the number of casts in your code to the bare minimum.

```
class idontknowwhat_t
{
    uint8_t* _data;

public:
    idontknowwhat_t(uint8_t* buffer)
        : _data(buffer)
    {}

    template<typename insert_type>
    idontknowwhat_t& operator<<(insert_type value)
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<insert_type*>(_data) = value;
        _data += sizeof(insert_type);
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename extract_type>
    idontknowwhat_t& operator>>(extract_type& value)
    {
        value = *reinterpret_cast<extract_type*>(_data);
        _data += sizeof(extract_type);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I think this will actually work directly with your code. In this example, the `idontknowwhat_t` class does not own the buffer and simply keeps a raw pointer to the next bit of data it expects to read or write. For real-life purposes I would recommend letting the `idontknowwhat_t` class manage the buffer memory.

In addition, none of the code on this page actually takes care of the data's endianness, which would definitely be the `idontknowwhat_t` class's responsibility. There is a [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html) for that. I'm not documenting that library's use here, since I think it distracts from the questions real point.

Comment: this looks fine. I am pretty sure that there are boost classes for all I need, but I didnt manage to adopt the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html) I found to what I need. As long as the receiver knows in advance what to receive its easy, but if the types in the message are encoded in the message itself I am quite lost. Btw that kind of cast I dont consider as ugly, because it is confined to only few lines and the caller wont notice its presence

Comment: Re "As long as the receiver knows in advance what to receive its easy, but if the types in the message are encoded in the message itself I am quite lost". This is different from the endianness thing.
The receiver must know something about what it is expecting -- at the very least, it must tell the `idontknowwhat_t` what datatype it wants the return value to have. Could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sure that comment was not concerning the endianness. What i mean is that the messages are not a fixed structure, but just follow a fixed protocol, eg. (staying with the example in the question) a certain value of the `id` might indicate that the next value is a `uint32_t` while another value might indicate that the next value is a `uint16_t`

Comment: ... actually in the real code the first two bytes is a `uint16_t` that indicates what will follow.

Comment: That sounds like it's the responsibility of your second piece of code. You would read the first `id` flag as a `uint16_t`, and put it into a switch statement. The different cases of this switch statement can read the buffer in whatever way they like.

Comment: btw not sure if there is a misunderstanding, my first comment was not trying to say that I have problems to adopt your answer, but rather about the problems using something not "selfmade"

Comment: You mean that you don't want to depend on boost unless you have to? I often think the same way. Taking care of endianness though, is one of those things that's difficult to do in a way that's both portable and efficient. Hence my recommending a library for that. If you know in advance that all your users are on the same platform, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: No, I mean I would like to use boost (cant use C++11), but after several days of reading stuff I still find it more difficult than using raw sockets and my homebrewn raw byte array

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/)? You could group the elements into types and put them into lists with the appropriate type. Then you could create an std::list of std::lists.

Comment: no I dont want to send lists across the network. I want to send a byte array, so I dont understand how a std::list would help